# mCustomScrollbar in jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dialog, mcustomscrollbar

When I updated `mCustomScrollbar` I encountered an issue with it showing inside the jQuery UI Dialog when neither a `height` nor `max-height` value is set. So this scroll is just showing when it is not needed and serves no purpose.

I went to Malihu & found there was only [one person](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/comment-page-77/#comment-21107) with my issue & no fix  yet.

Comment: Thank you for the minor edits. It's not like I needed an answer more than edits.

Comment: I ask that if you are going to have SO notify me due to minor edits you have made to my thought out question you provide me & the community with some helpful information, as well.